# Problems With JTable and Validation Engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, validation, jquery-validation-engine

i'm working in a site using PHP+JQuery. For CRUD operations i'm using JTable with validationEngine for form validation. I'm creating a new JQuery Dialog for Password Change, but validationEngine returns me "True" when i close and open again the password dialog. this is my full javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#catalogoAlumnos").jtable({
            title : 'Alumnos',
            sorting : true,
            actions : {
                listAction : '../php/alumnosActions/selectAlumnos.php',
                createAction : '../php/alumnosActions/agregarAlumno.php',
                updateAction : '../php/alumnosActions/updateAlumno.php',
                deleteAction : '../php/alumnosActions/deleteAlumno.php'
            },
            fields : {
                ficha : {
                    title : '',
                    width : '1%',
                    sorting : false,
                    edit : false,
                    create : false,
                    display : function(Data) {
                        var $img = $('<button class="jtable-command-button jtable-view-command-button" src="../style/jtable/metro/list.png" title="Ver Más..." />');
                        $img.click(function() {
                            var $div = $("<div id='dialog' title='Información'>" + "<strong><label class='jtable-input-label'>Nombre Completo: </label></strong>" + Data.record.apellidosalumno + " " + Data.record.nombresalumno + "<br>" + "<strong><label class='jtable-input-label'>Sexo: </label></strong>" + Data.record.sexoalumno + "<br>" + "<strong><label class='jtable-input-label'>Dirección Completa: </label></strong>" + Data.record.direccionalumno + ", " + Data.record.ciudadalumno + ", " + Data.record.estadoalumno + ", " + Data.record.paisalumno + "<br>" + "<strong><label class='jtable-input-label'>Periodo de Registro: </label></strong>" + Data.record.periodoregistroalumno + " Del " + Data.record.anoregistroalumno + "<br>" + "<strong><label class='jtable-input-label'>Periodo Actual: </label></strong>" + Data.record.periodoactualalumno + " Del " + Data.record.anoactualalumno + "<br>" + "<strong><label class='jtable-input-label'>Semestre: </label></strong>" + Data.record.semestrealumno + "</div>");
                            $div.dialog({
                                modal : true
                            });
                        });
                        return $img;
                    }
                },
                num_control : {
                    key : true,
                    title : 'No. Control',
                    create : true,
                    edit : false,
                    inputClass : 'validate[required]'
                },
                password : {
                    list : false,
                    title : 'Contraseña',
                    type : 'password',
                    create : true,
                    edit : false,
                    inputClass : 'validate[required]'
                },
                apellidosalumno : {
                    title : 'Apellidos',
                    inputClass : 'validate[required]'
                },
                nombresalumno : {
                    title : 'Nombre',
                    inputClass : 'validate[required]'
                },
                sexoalumno : {
                    list : false,
                    title : 'Sexo',
                    create : true,
                    edit : true,
                    options : {
                        'M' : 'Masculino',
                        'F' : 'Femenino'
                    }
                },
                direccionalumno : {
                    title : 'Dirección',
                    list : false,
                    create : true,
                    edit : true,
                    inputClass : 'validate[required]'
                },
                ciudadalumno : {
                    title : 'Ciudad',
                    list : false,
                    create : true,
                    edit : true,
                    inputClass : 'validate[required]'
                },
                estadoalumno : {
                    title : 'Estado',
                    list : false,
                    create : true,
                    edit : true,
                    inputClass : 'validate[required]'
                },
                paisalumno : {
                    title : 'Pais',
                    list : false,
                    create : true,
                    edit : true,
                    inputClass : 'validate[required]'
                },
                carreraalumno : {
                    title : 'Carrera',
                    options : '../php/carrerasActions/selectCarrerasDropDown.php'
                },
                periodoregistroalumno : {
                    title : 'Periodo de Registro',
                    options : {
                        '1' : 'Ene-Abril',
                        '2' : 'Mayo-Agosto',
                        '3' : 'Sep-Dic'
                    },
                    list : false,
                    create : true,
                    edit : true
                },
                anoregistroalumno : {
                    title : 'Año de Registro',
                    list : false,
                    create : true,
                    edit : true,
                    inputClass : 'validate[required,custom[integer],min[1980]]'
                },
                periodoactualalumno : {
                    title : 'Periodo Actual',
                    options : {
                        '1' : 'Ene-Abril',
                        '2' : 'Mayo-Agosto',
                        '3' : 'Sep-Dic'
                    },
                    list : false,
                    create : true,
                    edit : true
                },
                anoactualalumno : {
                    title : 'Año del Periodo Actual',
                    list : false,
                    create : true,
                    edit : true,
                    inputClass : 'validate[required,custom[integer],min[1980]]'
                },
                semestrealumno : {
                    title : 'Semestre',
                    inputClass : 'validate[required,custom[integer]]'
                },
                emailalumno : {
                    title : 'E-mail',
                    list : false,
                    create : true,
                    edit : true,
                    inputClass : 'validate[required,custom[email]]'
                },
                cambiar_password : {
                    title : '',
                    width : '1%',
                    sorting : false,
                    edit : false,
                    create : false,
                    display : function(Data) {
                        var $img = $('<button class="jtable-command-button jtable-password-command-button" title="Cambiar Contraseña" />');
                        $img.click(function() {
                            var $div = $("<div id='dialog2' title='Cambiar Contraseña'>" + "<form id='cambia_pass' class='jtable-dialog-form' style='-moz-column-count:auto;-webkit-column-count:auto;column-count:auto;-moz-column-gap:auto;-webkit-column-gap:auto;column-gap:auto;'>" + "<div class='jtable-input-field-container'>" + "<div class='jtable-input-label'>Antigua Contraseña</div>" + "<div class='jtable-input jtable-password-input'><input type='password' class='validate[required]' name='antiguo_pass' id='antiguo_pass'/></div>" + "</div>" + "<div class='jtable-input-field-container'>" + "<div class='jtable-input-label'>Escriba Contraseña</div>" + "<div class='jtable-input jtable-password-input'><input type='password' class='validate[required]' name='nuevo_pass1' id='nuevo_pass1'/></div>" + "</div>" + "<div class='jtable-input-field-container'>" + "<div class='jtable-input-label'>Repita Contraseña</div>" + "<div class='jtable-input jtable-password-input'><input type='password' class='validate[required],equals[nuevo_pass1]' name='nuevo_pass2 id='nuevo_pass2'/></div>" + "</div>" + "</form>" + "</div>");
                            $div.dialog({
                                modal : true,
                                close : function(event, ui) {
                                    $("#cambia_pass").validationEngine('hide');
                                    $("#cambia_pass").validationEngine('detach');
                                },
                                buttons : {
                                    "Actualizar" : function() {
                                        if ($("#cambia_pass").validationEngine('validate')) {

                                        }
                                    },
                                    "Cancelar" : function() {
                                        $("#cambia_pass").validationEngine('hide');
                                        $("#cambia_pass").validationEngine('detach');
                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        return $img;
                    }
                }
            },
            formSubmitting : function(event, data) {
                return data.form.validationEngine('validate');
            },
            formClosed : function(event, data) {
                data.form.validationEngine('hide');
                data.form.validationEngine('detach');
            }
        });
        $("#catalogoAlumnos").jtable('load');

        $('#cmdBuscar').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#catalogoAlumnos').jtable('load', {
                no_control : $('#search_nocontrol').val(),
                apellidos : $('#search_apellidos').val(),
                nombres : $('#search_nombres').val(),
                carrera : $('#search_carrera').val(),
                semestre : $('#search_semestre').val(),
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... insted of using `'detach'` and `'hide'` events, i removed directly the dialog from the DOM using `.remove()` from JQuery. so this code:

```
close : function(event, ui) {
    $("#cambia_pass").validationEngine('hide');
    $("#cambia_pass").validationEngine('detach');
}

became this:
close : function(event, ui) {
    $(this).remove();
}
```